# Should async be used if the operation is almost always completed quickly?

Tags: c#, async-await

Is there general advice on whether or not to use async when a potentially slow operation is fast almost all the time?

For example, Redis calls will usually return within a millisecond or two and practically always within 10ms. The one scenario where they would not is if there is a problem connecting. Then the retries will kick in and we may be waiting several seconds.

The guidance I see is to use async when the operation may take over 50ms, but it would be nice not to incur the overhead of async on every call when it's only helpful 0.1% of the time at most.

Is there a general strategy to use in such a scenario?

In my particular case I'm seeing Redis, SQL, and cloud storage calls complete in <20ms 99+% of the time, with outliers in the 1-60 second range when those services are temporarily unavailable. The application is a web service built on MVC serving around 100 requests a second. Practically every request uses one of these usually quick but potentially long running services.

Comment: My only experience with async is with JavaScript and usually there isn't a choice between async/non-async so regardless of the response time `await` is _always_ used. I don't think it really matters as the code still appears synchronous either way. You're also building in the ability to wait for longer responses automatically

Comment: 10ms surely is not quick and why would you lock your resources anyway - maybe your system will scale later on - so yes if you do IO and can use async - do it

Comment: @Bojangles It is C# - I added a tag, and there is often a choice if I use sync or async methods. Synchronous methods are almost always available.

Comment: @CarstenKönig If this were, say, a desktop application, blocking for 10ms would be something that an astute user might sometimes notice, but many wouldn't notice, and even if they noticed it, it's unlikely to actually be bothersome.  The general guidance I hear is that when you get up to 50ms of blocking the UI is when it tends to be worth making asynchronous in order to not negatively impact the user experience.

Comment: @CarstenKönig I should have clarified, this is a web service. If we use async we add overhead to every request.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to depend on context.  If the method is being called from, say, an ASP application, then having the method usually be very quick, but occasionally be time consuming, isn't really a problem.  The performance lost from the rare extended executions is likely to be less of a problem for a busy web server than the overhead of asynchrony on every single call that goes quickly.

However, if there is say a desktop UI application in which executing for an extended period of time is going to freeze the application for the user, that's (at least potentially) a serious problem, probably worse than the operation taking a few microsecond longer whenever it would normally be slow.  In such a context it's almost certainly preferable to do the work asynchronously.

So you have to do the analysis based on context.  If you knew the method would be long, why would you make it asynchronous; what problems would it cause?  Then compare that to the costs of adding a few microseconds to the execution times of the best case runs and see which is more of a problem for you.

Comment: The one major problem I'm aware of is that if we have a long period of a service being unavailable - say our SQL is offline for a minute - without async we'll likely reach IIS's limit on blocked threads or queued requests without additional strategies to avoid that in the absence of async. I know the right answer is profile and find out but I was hoping to solicit some opinions first.

Comment: @qes Then you need to weight the risk of that happening, and the consequences of it happening, to the cost of having every single request be just a teinsy bit longer.  Whether it's a risk you want to mitigate or simply accept is a decision you need to make; we can't make it for you.